# Show that $\langle a^k \rangle=G$ if and only if $(n,k)=1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> If $G=\langle a \rangle$ is cyclic of order $n$ show that $a^k$ is a generator if and only if $(n,k)=1$

So I was able to show that if $(n,k)=1$ then $\langle a^k \rangle=G$. However im not being able to show the converse. Any hint from where to start?

Comment: If $(n,k)>1$, then $(a^k)^{n/(n,k)}=(a^n)^{k/(n,k)}=1$.

Comment: Hint: $a^k$ generates $G$ iff there exists $m$ such that $(a^k)^m = a$.

Answer (score 1):

For the converse proof $a^k,a^{2k},......a^{nk}=1$ are all distinct elements. Let $(n,k)=t$, Let $(n,k)=t,$ and $n=tc,k=td$. Take $(a^k)^c=(a^{td})^c=(a^{tc})^d=(a^n)^d=e$ $\implies n|c$ also $c|n$ $\implies c=n$, $t=1$

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on my hint, then.

We know $a^k$ generates $G$ iff there exists $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $(a^k)^m = a$. Since $a$ has order $n$, this is the same as $mk + rn = 1$ for some $r \in \mathbb{Z}$. Bézout's identity implies this is equivalent to $(k,n)=1$.

(This proves both directions.)